# The map $X/A \to Y$ induced by $f:X \to Y$, which is nullhomotopic on $A\subset X$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Assume $(X,A)$ has the homotopy extension property (or even a CW pair). Suppose we are given a map $f : X \to Y$, such that the restriction $f|_A : A \to Y$ is nullhomotopic for some subspace $A \subset X$. Then, given a nullhomotopy $h : A \times I \to Y$, we can solve the homotopy extension problem and get a map $F : X \times I \to Y$ such that $$F|_{X\times 0} = f, \; F|_{A\times I} = h$$
In particular, $F|_{A\times 1} = h|_{A\times 1} = *$, and we have an induced map $g : X/A \to Y$.

**Question:** Does the map $g$ depends (up to homotopy) on the choice of the nullhomotopy?

Here is the example that I had in mind. Consider, $(X, A) = (D^2, S^1)$. Consider the map $f : D^2 \to S^2$ which maps identically onto the upper hemisphere. Now, $f|_{S^1}$ is clearly nullhomtopic, since $\pi_1(S^2)=0$. Denote by $h_u : S^1 \times I \to S^2$ the homotopy which slides the meridian circle over the upper hemisphere and to a point on the meridian (while keeping this point fixed). Denote by $h_l : S^1 \times I \to S^2$ the homtopy which slides along the lower hemisphere.

Then, it seems to me, that $h_u$ induces the constant map $D^2/S^1 \to S^2$, whereas $h_l$ induces the quotient map $D^2/S^1 \to S^2$. Clearly, these are not homotopic, since the quotient map is really the identity $S^2 \to S^2$.

Is my (non)example correct, or am I making some silly continuity mistake?! Any help is appreciated. Cheers!

Comment: You should not write $f : X \to Y$ and $f : X/A \to Y$.

Comment: @PaulFrost Edited the symbols.

Comment: Your example is correct. Think of a null homotopy of $f|_A$ as its extension to a map $F:CA\rightarrow Y$, where $CA$ is the cone over $A$. There is an induced map $\theta:X\cup CA\rightarrow Y$, where $X\cup CA$ is the mapping cone of the inclusion $i:A\subseteq X$. The homotopy class of $\theta$ is controlled by the homotopy class of $f$ rel $A$ and the homotopy class of $F$ rel $A$. (note that the obvious map $X\cup CA\rightarrow X/A$ is a homotopy equivalence when $i$ is a cofibration.)